# IIS 7.5 is not looking in bin folder for .dll's

Tags: visual-studio, iis, bin

I have an issue with my new web server.  Because it goes across a really slow WAN connection, I've installed VS2012 on the server and pointed the source folder to C:\Src.  This way I don't have to publish all my .dll's across the WAN.

It is also running a live IIS server, which points to C:\inetpub\wwwroot.

The VS2012 is really only there so I can get the source files quickly and build/publish.  That part works fine.

However, it appears as though IIS is looking under my C:\Src\xxxx\bin folder for the .dll's instead of the c:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxx\bin.

Any ideas how I can tell IIS to look under it's own bin folder instead of the src one?  Would this be a setting in the web.config?

Comment: How are you publishing the app to IIS?

Comment: Using the VS Web 1 click publish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it points to your Src directory, most likely you've accidentally set up a virtual directory in IIS when debugging.

Go into IIS manager and see if there is any virtual directory pointing to the wrong place.

Comment: That was exactly the problem! I guess VS decided to modify the virtual directory whether I told it to or not.